# C - issue with reading in from command line - assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, io

Having an issue with reading in from the command line into an array of integers.

Intent is to parse the entered line by spaces/tabs and then atoi() each individual number into the appropriate array slot.

Relevant code:

**main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "functions.h"

int main()
{
    int nums[100];
    int count = 0;

    readInput(&nums, &count);

    return 0;
}
```

**functions.h**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#ifndef FUNCTIONS_H_INCLUDED
#define FUNCTIONS_H_INCLUDED

void readInput(int *nums[], int *count);

#endif // FUNCTIONS_H_INCLUDED
```

**functions.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "functions.h"

#define delims " \t\r\n"

#define MAX_LEN 128

void readInput(int *nums[], int *count)
{

    char *input = malloc(MAX_LEN);
    char *buffer;

    gets(input);

    buffer = strtok(input, delims);

    nums[(*count)++] = atoi(buffer);

    while ((buffer = strtok(NULL, delims)) != NULL)
        nums[(*count)++] = atoi(buffer);

    buffer = strtok(NULL, delims);
}
```

The lines in **functions.c** with **nums[(*count)++] = atoi(buffer);** are flagging with the warning **"warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast"**.

And from **main.c**, the line **readInput(&nums, &count);** is flagging with **"warning: passing argument 1 of 'readInput' from incompatible pointer type"**.

The odd thing is this program works when run and any attempts to add in casting or dereferencing has resulted in the warnings being subdued, but the program crashing when run.

Comment: `int *nums[]` is an array of pointers to int, not an array of ints.

Comment: As a general rule, any time you see the warning *"assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast"*, it means you have a problem with the *level of indirection* at the line identified by the compiler. The warning is actually very good. It tells you you are trying to assign an *integer* while using a *pointer* as your lvalue. e.g. `int a = 6; int *b = a;` With `b` declared as a pointer and used as an lvalue, you try and assign `a` to `b` where `a` is and *integer* and `b` is a *pointer*. To fix it, you would need `b = &a;` which would then assign the *address of* `a` to `b`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you declare your function:

```
void readInput(int *nums[], int *count);
```

the argument declaration `int *nums[]` is an *array of pointers*, not a pointer to an array which is what you call it like with `&nums`.

However, you don't *need* to pass a pointer to the array here. Arrays naturally decays to pointers to their first element. And when you declare an array as an argument to a function (like the declaration of `nums` in the function prototype above) it's really a pointer.

When you declare function arguments, a declaration like `int nums[]` is the same as `int *nums`.

So the declaration of `readInput` should really be

```
void readInput(int *nums, int *count);
```

If you do that change (including the function definition of course), and call it like

```
readInput(nums, &count);
```

then everything should work out fine.

Comment: This works. Thanks a lot. Normally a Java programmer, so having a lot of fun with this baptism by fire.